# Singularitygs - center divs using grid-span location and output-style 'float'

Tags: css, singularitygs

I have a 14 column grid called `.container`. I am trying to center 4 divs having the class `.block` within `.container` where each `.block` spans 3 columns.

I'd like to accomplish this by adding one positioning rule to `.block` instead of adding an isolation style to each `.block`.

Based on my understanding of Singularitygs, I should use output-style float to position multiple divs with the same class relative to one another.

Ideally, I could use `@include grid-span(3, 2, $output-style: 'float');` where location is 2, but location seems to be ineffective. According to the documentation, location is optional. But does this imply that it is ignored? https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/wiki/Spanning-The-Grid#float-span

If location is not effective with `grid-span(3, 2, $output-style: 'float');`, does anyone know an alternative solution that is simple and elegant? I'd like to avoid generating additional elements in the DOM or positioning each individual `.block` element.

I've created a gist on sassmeister here:
http://sassmeister.com/gist/5e92b58e8bb2a206a228

And a summary of the code I am using is here:

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block'> </div>
  <div class='block'> </div>
  <div class='block'> </div>
  <div class='block'> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@include add-grid(14);

.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  @include grid-span(3, 2, $output-style: 'float');
  height: 25px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add a grid-span percentage (column + gutter) as left margin to the first `.block`.

This value can be retrieved via the grid-span function which is exposed by the Singularity API. Specifically, it returns "a percentage equal to the column-span at a given span and location plus a gutter-span". https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/wiki/Grid-Helpers

In the case above, since we want 1 column plus gutter's worth of space on each side of our 4 `.block`'s, we use

```
.block:first-of-type {
  margin-left: grid-span(1, 1);
}
```

Here is an updated gist showing the centered divs using this approach: http://sassmeister.com/gist/27e13cc4ae586f2f885f

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap the block divs in another div and center that, then the blocks can stack nicely within it.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/503b1301a0969c9395ad